# Why are my browser requests to visit W3.org redirected to Mozilla.org?

Tags: redirect, browser

A google search -html map element site:w3.org- returns a hit with the link advertised as "https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/map". (That appears both at the bottom of the browser window, and in the popup i see by clicking the ellipsis.  The actual link behind the hit text is a great long google hash, but when I paste the address, that should not matter.  I think.)

If I click on the link, OR paste that w3.org address into FF or Chrome's address bar, I go instead to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map.

Why?  Is W3.org really redirecting me to Mozilla?  While I have great faith in Mozilla, I thought W3 to be the "ultimate authority".  If so, how do I find what they have to say on the topic of a MAP?

Sorry if the "tags" are inappropriate, I cannot think of others, nor a better way or place to ask this rather embarrassing question.

Comment: If you want to know why the W3C does something, I am afraid you will have to ask the W3C, not us. [so] is a website for programmers, not mind-readers.

Comment: Nobody's supposed to be a min-reader, @JörgWMittag. Stack Overflow is a platform that allows users to point to the source where to find an answer. Hence, after confirming that w3.org does an HTTP301 redirect to developer.mozilla.org, providing a link to the reason of that, would provide the expected answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The W3C Wiki does appear to have shut down and redirects to MDN, but the W3C Wiki was never authoritative (and, afaik, always user editable).

The HTML specification used to be available at `https://w3.org/TR/html5/` but that now redirects to WHATWG's site since they write the specification these days.